# How to pick/calculate component values for a tuned amplifier centered on 13.56Mhz?

Tags: amplifier, bjt

**Background**

As a fun / learning project I wanted to build a circuit which can tell me if a given RFID reader on a wall is 125Khz or 13.56Mhz ( by lighting LEDs).
My approach is to build two filters which lead to diode detectors - one filter + detector for 125khz, and one for 13.56Mhz.

I was hoping to use a length of wire or an unmeasured coil of wire as the input (pickup).

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to calculate values for the tuned circuit - I havent found any online calculator or sensible derivation (I don't understand the math/electronics enough to do it from first principles, I know Ohms law + basic AC theory + putting numbers into formulas).

Complication: I cant give an exact value of the 'drive' (input impedance?) of the input coil, nor can I work out the impedance of the diode envelope detector on the amps output. Can we just guess these?

**The whole circuit so far, including the 125Khz section**

[image: Full circuit]

Why cant HF be as easy as 125Khz? Cheap op-amps work at 125Khz.

**The tuned amplifier schematic so far**

[image: Tuned amp]

Comment: gain-bandwidth product

Comment: 125 kHz and 13.56 MHz are more than a factor 100 apart yet you want to pickup those signals with one antenna. This means sensitivity will be bad for one or both frequencies (assume both). **I doubt you will get this to work properly**. Often "designing" something without the proper background knowledge will end in failure and disappointment. The fact that you need to "guess" also does not inspire me with confidence. It is OK to guess but that should be an **educated guess** meaning, you can explain the order of magnitude of the parameter values. As frequencies go up, this becomes more true.

Comment: I was hoping that, because of the high power being emitted by an RFID reader, that even a small coil of wire would be driven at a few volts P2P.
If not, I can play around with swapping in different antenna coils. For the sake of the question, I think we can assume I have a reasonable antenna or a 'high drive' on the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could design two seperate  tuned      loop antennas one by one .If you dont load the tuned circuit too much by say using a high input impedance preamp like say a MPF102 JFET .This means that the Q will be high in both cases and the standard formulae for resonant frequency of a tuned circuit will work fine .I have not done any 125KHz or 13.56 MHz work but I think that any open field coil would work as a receiving antenna .A bundle of ferrite rods from dead transistor AM radios would work at 125KHz .The proposed use of N bundled rods rather than just one will reduce the number of turns needed in rough proportion .Litz wire is actually still beneficial at 125 KHz because you will need lots of turns .If you dont want to do litz then consider space winding or wave winding or bank winding or any other technique to reduce proximity effect and parasitic capacitance .Coils with low parasitic capacitance tend to have higher Q which for your application means better sensitivity and batter selectivity .The 13.58 MHz is better on solid wire because     normal litz thinks that it is solid above about 3 MHz due to its significant capacitance .You could use a ferrite rod or an air cored multi turn loop with good results .If you get the Antennas right with high Q then you have enough selectivity to differentiate these far apart signals .

Answer (score 0):

Last time I made a 13.56Mhz receiver I used a single square loop of wire and a resonatign capacitor in parallel with the loop antenna.

The antenna was a square loop having edges of about 8 inches each.  An 8 inch square loop will form an inductor of about 737nH.  You can find a coil inductance calculator here...

https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/rectangle-loop-inductance

The resonatign capacitor needs to be chosen such that it resonates with the antenna inductance at 13.56MHz.

The resonant frequency of an LC circuit is...

w = 1/sqrt(L * C)

so...

C = 1/(w^2 * L) = 1/ ((2 * pi * 13.56MHz)^2 * 737nH) = 187pF

It is likely that parasitic capacitances and inductances will be important in the circuit so you may want to make the capacitor a little less than 187pF and then add a variable capacitor to tune the circuit.  Or alternately make the capacitor a little smaller and add a variable inductor.

Comment: When you say a capacitor in parallel to the loop, do you mean one side of both the loop and cap go to ground, and the other side of both loop and cap go to the filter's input?

Comment: And whats w? is w just 2 * pi * f?

Comment: @64bit_twitchyliquid yes, w = 2 * pi * f.  You can terminate the antenna to a differential amplifier, or put one side to ground and the other to a single ended amplifier.